# How do I get backslashes to save?

Tags: 7, nodes

Everytime that I type a backslash into a textbox on my drupal site (in content editors, administration pages, you name it; I mean *any* textbox), it gets filtered out before it reaches the module code.

So I end up typing something like this:

> This is just some content with an \n
>   or a directory structure like
>   C:\Program Files\whatever

And it gets converted to this on save:

> This is just some content with an n
>   or a directory structure like
>   C:Program Fileswhatever

This really makes it hard to edit content on my D6 site; anyone know a fix for this?

Related issues:

- http://drupal.org/node/673748
- http://drupal.org/node/564166

[image: before submit]
[image: after submit]

This is on admin pages; so filters aren't used.

Comment: I can not reproduce this.

Check what filters you have enabled on the input format you are using and/or try a different one.

Comment: have you tried escaping the backslash?

Comment: This is a workaround; the escaped backslashes turn into only one backslash, but I think it's the best answer I'll get.

Comment: glad it worked out for you! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like it may be a [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/magic_quotes) issue. If at all possible, disable this in your PHP configuration. [Instructions on how to disable them are on the PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php). If this is enabled on a live, shared server and you don't have access to the PHP configuration then I would highly recommend looking for a new host. The `magic_quotes_gpc` option has been deprecated in PHP 5.3, and will likely be removed very soon.

Magic quotes provide a way of escaping incoming input, and have been frowned on for quite a while in favor of validating input properly in your application, which Drupal does.

Comment: yep... phpinfo comes out w/ --enable-magic-quotes. Thanks for the helpful answers.

Comment: @geoff: There's instructions for how to disable them in the links in my answer. I'd definitely try this first if at all possible because this sounds like it's the problem.

Comment: Yes, it's them problem. I've fixed it with a bit of PHP code in bootstrap.php. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @geoff if this actually solved your problem, then you can change the accepted answer to this to signify to future people looking for your issue that this is the correct solution.

Comment: Yes, but this answer and the above answer are kind of the same...